# How to insert my data in my table without getting any error?

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error, runtime-error

** mysql script is the following. what i'm doing wrong with it? i am trying to insert my data into my table but it seems impossibl as i am receiving lots of errors. how can i fix this script ? i am using phpmyadmin for my connection**

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitors (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  country varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  coffee int(11),
  tea int(11),
  mate int(11),
  cocoa int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY id (int)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int)

)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 8

Comment: "...i am receiving lots of errors" - please edit your question using the `edit` button just above the comments and let us know what those errors are. Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the single quotes around column names.

Comment: you do know `VALUES` ... can include more than once row? [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: @jingledev27 ok ... and now for learning matter , you try to write this in one transaction like danblack has suggested ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the right syntax, try it like this :

```
INSERT INTO visitors  (`id`,`country`,`coffee`,`tea`,`mate`, `cocoa`) VALUES (0,'Algeria','79','5','0','1');
```

Comment: or if backtick quoting it tedious, just omit those until you get a reserved word you need to quote.

Comment: @danblack yes it works like you propose, but I am 'oldscool' and I even use \`table\`.\`column\` to avoid confusions